# Using Logic Apps to read Excel from sharepoint online and then inserting into Azure SQL

Tags: excel, azure-sql-database, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to do something that should be fairly simple, but I get no results.
I want to read an Excel file from our sharepoint site (O365) and insert the data from the first worksheet into a table in SQL Server.

Actually quite simple and straightforward. Well, it sounds like that.......
Apparently there is more than reading the file and inserting the file into SQL Server....
Who can provide me with info, tutorials or (even better) step-by-step instructions?

Bonus would be looping through the (online) folder and importing all excel files creating a table for each worksheet.

Edit: I am able to collect the Excel file and email it to me as an attachment.
I just have no clue how to insert it in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible in 4 steps:

1. Trigger (duh)
2. Excel Business component - Get Tables
3. For each component - Value (list of items)
4. SQL Server component - Insert Row (V2) _ make sure you create parameters for all the columns and map them to the dynamic content offered

(I inserted  a SQL Server component - Execute query after step 2  to truncate the destination table)

Not looping yet but this at least enables me to insert rows from an online Excel into a Azure SQL

Answer (score -1):

You can use Azure Data Factory for that, create the connection to your excel file, then to SQL, and use a copy & transform Pipeline

[image: Azure Data Factory Pipeline]

Comment: Isn't Data Factory hellish expensive?

Comment: You only pay for the compute time, so you can have up to $1 / 1,000 activity runs per month, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/

Comment: I see only the option to import from csv ?

Comment: you can import from any file format: csv, json, other clouds